# jqx grid with autorowheight and fixed headed

Tags: jquery, jqxgrid

How can someone use jqxGrid to create a table that has headers that not moving when scrolling and also auto row height ?

I  did the following but the result is an auto row height but a header that moves when scrolling.

```
$("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid({
 widht:"100%",
 showfilterrow:true,
 filterable:true,
 autorowheight:true,
 autoheight:true,
 altrows:true
 columns: [//some columns here]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can activate the scrollbars within the grid so that the headers remain visible as you scroll down the content.  Do this by setting autoheight to false and specifying a fixed height.

```
$("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid({
 width:"100%",
 showfilterrow:true,
 filterable:true,
 autorowheight:true,
 autoheight:false,
 height:500
 altrows:true
 columns: [//some columns here]
}
```

You can try it out in [JqWidget's jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jqwidgets/cBeq7/) by setting the autorowheight to false.

Answer (score 0):

autoheight: false, pageable: true is your solution. The header is with Fixed position by default when the scrolling comes from jQWidgets Grid. If autoheight is true, jqxGrid's vertical scrolling is disabled because Grid's height is the sum of all rows height so if there is a scrollbar it is the browser's scrollbar and your Grid's height could be 5000px.